# Replacing a HP LaserJet 6L printer - what is today's equivalent from HP's range?

Tags: printer

What's the successor to the Hewlett Packard LaserJet 6L?

The printer was **sturdy** (it would still work away happily nearly 15 years later, if there were still drivers for Windows and LTP connectors on computers), its **print quality** excellent (no smearing toner when you used a highlighter on a printed page, no creases on a page, crisp, clean print-outs), and the **toner cheap** (35 EUR or 38 USD per 2500 pages, approx, i.e. 1.4EURct/1.52USDct). And it was fairly **compact**, with a [small footprint](http://www.cnet.com/products/hp-laserjet-6l/specs/) on a desk.

Any suggestions what printer from HP's current range might replace it?